# Increasing numbers over 100 batch files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file for Windows 7 that will create 100 text files with names - ex1 to ex100. In each file i need to replace a given text (eg. ex3) with the same text as the name of the file.

So far I have managed to get the batch file to create the 100 files however the text (ex3) is replaced by ex1 in each file.

Here is the code that I have used.  I am a complete novice to this and have cobbled it together from bits that I have found.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("c:\batch\batch.txt") DO (
  Set Line=%%G
  Set Line=!Line:"='!
  Call:replace "!Line!"
)

pause


goto:eof ------------
  :replace subroutine
  (Set Line=%*&Set Line=!Line:~1,-1!)
  Set Line=!Line:'="!

For /l %%A in (7,1,100) do Set "Line=!Line:ex3=ex%%A!"  
For /l %%n in (1,1,100) do echo.!Line! >>"c:\batch\ex%%n.txt"

 goto:eof ------------
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow - that code is way more convoluted than is needed (and also slow because of CALL).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "folder=c:\batch"
for /l %%N in (1 1 100) do del "%folder%\ex%%N.txt" 2>nul
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%folder%\batch.txt") do (
  set "line=%%A"
  for /l %%N in (1 1 100) do (echo !line:ex3=ex%%N!)>>"%folder%\ex%%N"
)
```

Comment: Works a treat!  As a follow up - I want it to work with non integer numbers. But if I change the (1 1 100) to say (0.1 0.1 10) it doesn't work.  Any ideas?