# Create a new file with increment number from batch

Tags: batch-file

I was looking for batch script to create a new folder with incremental number.

Example:

```
DirectroryNames= 
DirectoryName_1_Label234_Date
DirectoryName_2_Label235_Date
```

I want to create a new directory every time  batch script runs

```
DirectoryName_3_Label236_Date
```

next

```
DirectoryName_4_Label137_Date etc...
```

Any help ?

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964356/increasing-numbers-over-100-batch-files?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could have two variables that both increase. Take a look at this snippet and see if you like it...

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set start1=7
set start2=256
set end1=12
set end2=261
set /a amount=start2-start1

for /l %%i in (1,1,%amount%) do (
if DirectoryName_%start1%_Label1%start2%_Date exist goto end
md DirectoryName_%start1%_Label%start2%_Date
set /a start1+=1
set /a start2+=1
if %start1% geq %end1% goto end
)

:end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  When i run, i get error C:\File1>
C:\File1>CreateDirectory.bat
A subdirectory or file DirectoryName_7_Label256_Date already exists.

Comment: When i run, i get error C:\File1>
C:\File1>CreateDirectory.bat
A subdirectory or file DirectoryName_7_Label256_Date already exists.

Comment: Did you run the script more than once?

Comment: Yes , I want the directory name to increment the number

Comment: For Example: DirectoryName_1_Label234_Date DirectoryName_2_Label234_Date DirectoryName_3_Label234_Date

Comment: Well, there's you problem. It creates folders when it is run, if you run it more than once then there is going to be conflict. Delete the folders and do it again. It'll work.

Comment: ...But now that you mentioned it, I'll edit the script to end if there is already a file of that name.

Comment: ...Wait, do you mean every time it is run it creates another folder?

Comment: Yes, When ever i run the batch, it has to create the new directory with Name DirectorName_NextNumber_Label_NextNumber_%data%

Comment: Oh, while I create more code, please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: This works for me, but i need the directory in DirectorName_NextNumber_LabelNextNumber_%date%  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328421/how-do-i-increment-a-folder-name-using-windows-batch

Comment: So you want the directory of the folders...?

Comment: Script has to create the new Directories in DirectorName_NextNumber_LabelNextNumber_%date% format